# Free Music for DAW Practice

Tags: mixing, daw

I'm wondering if there are sites there with Creative Commons (or similar) music that is not already mixed down as an MP3, but rather with all the individual files (instruments, vocals, etc.) intact to download so that I can download them and mix it myself as well as add effects and do other processing.

It seems like a good way to practice editing and mixing with a DAW since I don't have the equipment needed to create high quality recording (especially vocals). Are there any sites that freely and legally supply this?

Comment: Not free, but I recommend [DigitalJuice StackTraxx](http://www.digitaljuice.com/products/product_lines.asp?plid=11) for layered music. Might not be exactly what you're looking for because the individual tracks have been "mastered", so it will not really help to learn skills like applying compression and eq, but it will help finding your way around the DAW and have some creative fun. Your end result will be royalty free, so that's a plus.

Answer (score 5):

[Shaking Through](http://www.shakingthrough.com/) let's you download unprocessed tracks and/or stems. I found it useful for getting started because the tracks are laid down by pros in a professional studio, so you don't have to worry about fixing bad tracks and can focus on mixing.

http://www.cambridge-mt.com/ms-mtk.htm has a huge collection of unprocessed multitracks, but some of the tracks may be less than stellar. It's a companion site to Mike Senior's book, "Mixing Secrets for the Small Studio".

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.cambridge-mt.com/ms-mtk.htm) (http://www.cambridge-mt.com/ms-mtk.htm) you can find an online download library of more than 50 unprocessed multitrack projects, all of which are free to use for educational purposes. Each project is provided as a simple ZIP archive containing WAV files at 24-bit/44.1kHz resolution, which can easily be imported into practically any DAW system. In addition to the full-length versions, most of the projects are also provided in a shorter excerpted form (usually comprising just the production's final chorus), catering for those with slower internet connections, as well as providing 'bite-sized' assignments for classroom use.

Answer (score 1):

If you join mp3unsigned.com and get onto their forum, there'll be folk on there who will let you have their individual music-track files. I've been a member for ages and I know this goes on.

Link to main site: - http://www.mp3unsigned.com/

Link to forum: - http://forum.mp3unsigned.com/

I'm not in the business of remixes but then again my stuff is mainly prog rock LOL

Comment: If you can't point to a definitive source, then at least offer some choice between different forums that you think might be a better place than AVP.stackexchange for this question. At the moment, your answer has a bit of an advertisement character.

Comment: @leftaroundabout should I list a few more unsigned music sites do you think? I'll also edit my question to make it a little less like an advertisement.

Comment: Ill be good if you posted some more to choose from.

Comment: And are there any sites where it's more simple to get the files (rather than asking random members on the forum)

Comment: If you go on the forum you can post a general request under http://forum.mp3unsigned.com/collaboration-corner/ I also have to say that mp3unsigned is your best bet. What sort of genre are you looking for?

Comment: Don't really care about the genre much... however your link seems to be more with artists collaborating with each other than people posting tracks to mix (I have a MIDI keyboard, but I want to practice mixing and effects with a variety of instrumentsbefore actually making music)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of musical works that have been released legally in a stem format for public use on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_works_released_in_a_stem_format